# dplyr recast - variable not found

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

First, here is the data `tbl_df` (simplified) I am using :

```
> mytbldf
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]

  iso2c country year     var1      var2
1    BI Burundi 2011 4.486265  6.693711
2    BI Burundi 2012 3.939242  5.330326
3    BI Burundi 2013 4.286439  5.747370
4    UG  Uganda 2011 3.998849 10.025680
5    UG  Uganda 2012 4.606198 13.416311
6    UG  Uganda 2013 4.746322 15.981362
```

I want to spread (in tidyr wording) the year variable over `var1` and `var2`.
After some (...) iterations, I found a syntax that works:

```
> recast(mytbldf, iso2c + country ~ variable + year, measure.var = c("var1","var2"))
  iso2c country var1_2011 var1_2012 var1_2013 var2_2011 var2_2012 var2_2013
1    BI Burundi  4.486265  3.939242  4.286439  6.693711  5.330326   5.74737
2    UG  Uganda  3.998849  4.606198  4.746322 10.025680 13.416311  15.98136
```

Three questions:

**1)** if I don't specify `measure.var =`, I get the following error:

```
> recast(mytbldf, iso2c + country ~ variable + year)
Using iso2c, country as id variables
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'year' not found
```

Why is that? From `recast`'s man, I assumed it would take `measure.var` as all other variables?

**2)** So, is there a way to avoid specifying `measure.var`? In my real case, there are too many variables with too long names for explicitly specifying them.

**3)** Is there a better/simpler way to do that using `reshape2` or `tidyr` that I am missing?

Comment: Re: your third question, I think no in `tidyr`.  Doing this in `tidyr` would require individual calls of `spread` for each variable you want to spread (two in your example but it sounds like more in your actual data) and then combining the results.  According to [Hadley's tidy data paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), your data are already tidy, which may be why this sort of operation is not supported.

Comment: @SamFirke: you're right, the data is already tidy indeed. What I need to do now is the last step, where i have to produce (messy) outputs that can be injected in XLS spreadsheets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the `devel` version of `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(mytbldf), iso2c+country~year, value.var=c('var1', 'var2'))
#    iso2c country 2011_var1 2012_var1 2013_var1 2011_var2 2012_var2 2013_var2
#1:    BI Burundi  4.486265  3.939242  4.286439  6.693711  5.330326   5.74737
#2:    UG  Uganda  3.998849  4.606198  4.746322 10.025680 13.416311  15.98136
```

Or using `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(mytbldf, idvar=c('iso2c', 'country'), timevar='year', 
                 direction='wide')
#  iso2c country var1.2011 var2.2011 var1.2012 var2.2012 var1.2013 var2.2013
#1    BI Burundi  4.486265  6.693711  3.939242  5.330326  4.286439   5.74737
#4    UG  Uganda  3.998849 10.025680  4.606198 13.416311  4.746322  15.98136
```

Regarding `recast` it is just `melt` + `dcast`.  So, if you are not specifying the `id.var` or `measure.var` in `melt`, the `long` format will be different than what you expected.  For `recast`, you can specify the `id.var` as

```
  library(reshape2)
  recast(mytbldf, id.var=c('iso2c', 'country', 'year'),
            iso2c+country~variable+year)
  #  iso2c country var1_2011 var1_2012 var1_2013 var2_2011 var2_2012 var2_2013
  #1    BI Burundi  4.486265  3.939242  4.286439  6.693711  5.330326   5.74737
  #2    UG  Uganda  3.998849  4.606198  4.746322 10.025680 13.416311  15.98136
```

Also, if you know the column index, it would be easier than typing the names,

```
 recast(mytbldf, measure.var=4:5,  iso2c+country~variable+year)
 #   iso2c country var1_2011 var1_2012 var1_2013 var2_2011 var2_2012 var2_2013
 #1    BI Burundi  4.486265  3.939242  4.286439  6.693711  5.330326   5.74737
 #2    UG  Uganda  3.998849  4.606198  4.746322 10.025680 13.416311  15.98136
```